# Jquery switch statement works occasionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, jquery-animate, switch-statement

I am quite new to writing my own jquery functions and I find debugging it very difficult as the error messages aren't too helpful when put into google.

I have a navigation menu for page anchors that when each one is clicked the screen scrolls to the anchor, the elements will change color depending on which one and the hover color will also change. Very simple really, I think.

The scrolling always works, the animate works occasionally and the hover works put usually I have to click the link twice. The return false only works on the first link you click.

This uses the scrollTo and animate-colors plugins.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(".scrolltoanchor").click(function() {
                                $('a').removeClass('selected');
                                $(this).addClass('selected');
        $.scrollTo($($(this).attr("href")), {
            duration: 750
        });

        switch ($(this).attr("id")) {
            case 'personal':
            $('.scrolltoanchor').animate({color: '#E4D8B8'});
            $(".scrolltoanchor").hover(
            function() {
            $(this).css('color', 'blue');
            },function(){
            $(this).css('color', '#E4D8B8');
            });
            break;

            case 'achievements':
            $('.scrolltoanchor').animate({color: '#ffffff'});
            $(".scrolltoanchor").hover(
            function() {
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
            },function(){
            $(this).css('color', '#ffffff');
            });
            break;

            case 'skills':
            $('.scrolltoanchor').animate({color: '#dddddd'});
            $(".scrolltoanchor").hover(
            function() {
            $(this).css('color', 'orange');
            },function(){
            $(this).css('color', '#ffffff');
            });
            break;


        }

        return false;
    });
```

Sorry to ask to be spoonfed, but I have followed what I believed to be the correct syntax from what I have learnt. Is there something I should know that is stopping this working as I expect?

EDIT: Sorry I forgot, I get this error on the (on average) every second click of a scrolltoanchor link

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

I can't spot a real pattern. Sometimes it seems to happen only on ones that havent been clicked before, sometimes not.
Thanks

Comment: I looks like the hover wont be applied until you click one of the links, is this correct? If the return false isn't cancelling the click event then there is an error in your handler (but I can't find it).

Comment: I will add a tip: you're using `$('.scrolltoanchor')` a lot. If the result never changes (ie. it always returns the same nodes) then you can best store the result in a variable, this will make your script much faster although I doubt you'll see any performance issues with just a few nodes, just something to keep in mind ;)

Comment: Yeah, I basically want the entire site color scheme to change when the link is clicked, changing the color of elements with that class, and so yeah the hover colors change when the link is click.
Thanks for the tip about performance, this will be the extent of the nodes tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're taking the wrong approach.

You should bind the hover handlers once, and decide the colors based on which one was clicked.

Simplest way would probably to store the color data in a lookup table where the keys are the IDs of the elements.

```
var ids = {
    personal: {
        over:'blue',
        out:'#E4D8B8'
    },
    achievements: {
        over:'red',
        out:'#ffffff'
    },
    skills: {
        over:'orange',
        out:'#dddddd'
    }
};
var current = ids.personal;
```

Then bind the handlers once, and use the `id` of the one clicked to set the `current` color set.

```
var scroll_anchors = $(".scrolltoanchor");

scroll_anchors.hover( function() {
    $(this).css( 'color', current.over );
},function(){
    $(this).css( 'color', current.out );
});

scroll_anchors.click(function() {
     $('a.selected').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');

     $.scrollTo($($(this).attr("href")), { duration: 750 });

     current = ids[ this.id ]; // set the current color set based on the ID

     scroll_anchors.animate({ color: current.out });

     return false;
});
```

Comment: I couldn't muster the courage to write this up, so an upvote is the least I can do here.

Comment: Thanks @Jon. I know exactly what you mean.

Comment: Nice, I finish editing my answer with some beautiful code only to find you beat me to it.  Amazingly similar code.  I'll delete mine.

Comment: This is great, completely new ground for me. I do understand it, but I don't see why the hover functionality isn't working, I get each .scrolltoanchor flickering to orange only the first time it is hovered over (likely as this is the existing css settings), then permanently changes to whatever 'out' is. 'Over' is being set as I checked with an alert, but its not being used.

Comment: Never mind, it was just a space in the selector. Brilliant, thanks very much!

Comment: @MichaelMallett: Glad it worked. Yeah, I caught that space a little late.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `.hover()` multiple times, you aren't removing the old event handlers, you are just adding a new one.  Each handler will be called each time.  You'll want to call `.unbind("hover")` first:

```
$(".scrolltoanchor").unbind("hover").hover(function () {
    ...
});
```

You can also bind to hover outside of the switch statement to eliminate some of the code duplication:

```
$(".scrolltoanchor").click(function () {
    $('a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $.scrollTo($(this.href), {
        duration: 750
    });
   var off, on;
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'personal':
            off = '#E4D8B8';
            on = 'blue';
            break;
        case 'achievements':
            off = '#ffffff';
            on = 'red';
            break;
        case 'skills':
            off = '#dddddd';
            on = 'orange';
            break;
    }

    $('.scrolltoanchor')
        .animate({ color: off })
        .unbind("hover")
        .hover(function () {
            $(this).css('color', on);
        }, function () {     
            $(this).css('color', off);
        });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I've just tried adding $(this).unbind('hover') in each case (before the new hover function), then I tried just adding it once just before the switch statement. Neither worked. I also tried $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave'). ?

Comment: Not `$(this).unbind("hover")`.  You need to unbind *all* the links.  Use `$('.scrolltoanchor').unbind('hover')`.

Comment: Thanks. Also, thanks for your code that was similar to above!